# What to do when my scope does not fit into any master scope?

Tags: unity, 13.10, clipboard, scopes

I have created my own unity scope following [this tutorial](http://developer.ubuntu.com/scopes/tutorial/) which works very well.

For now I have added it to the Info master scope, however it does not really fit there or in any other master scope. Do I need to create my own master scope? If yes how do I go about this?

Comment: In my case it is a clipboard manager scope accessing the clipboard history which could be split into categories such as Recent, Text, Files and Images. However I want to keep this question General as the question about creating a master scope yes or no resp. how remains the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a discussion I had on IRC Freenode #ubuntu-unity I have now a solution which I wanted to share.

It is fairly easy to turn an ordinary scope into a master scope. To start just create a normal scope e.g. by following [the scope tutorial.](http://developer.ubuntu.com/scopes/tutorial/)

The only thing which needs to be different is the scope file. Instead of copying it into a specific scope your directly copy it into /usr/share/unity/scopes/. Additionally in the scope file add IsMaster in the scope section

```
[Scope]
...
IsMaster=true
```

As a master scope can define its own filters and categories add those as needed to your scope file as well. Here an example I copied from the files.scope file:

```
[Category recent]
Name=Recent
Icon=/usr/share/icons/unity-icon-theme/places/svg/group-recent.svg
DedupField=uri

[Filter type]
Name=Type
Type=filter-checkoption
SortType=display-name
OptionIDs=documents;folders;images;audio;videos;presentations;other;
OptionNames=Documents;Folders;Images;Audio;Videos;Presentations;Other;
```

Per default won't your new master scope show up as an icon on the dash. If you want to do so you will need to change gsettings which you can do with the following command:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Dash scopes "['home.scope', 'applications.scope', 'files.scope', 'video.scope', 'music.scope', 'photos.scope', 'social.scope', 'mynewmaster.scope']"
```

Replace mynewmaster.scope with the name of your scope. Done.